# Android Studio API level error for Android Wear

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am trying to run and test a simple android application using android studio(version 3.0.1) on a smartwatch, I am getting the below error with respect to the gradle sync. (I am creating an new project by selecting the wear with the API level of 22 which is same as smartwatch API level).

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 22 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [com.android.support:wear:26.1.0] C:\Users\Sai.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\wear-26.1.0.aar\5b2a40104c2cc0843c9e44597771b49a\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 22
>       Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 22,
>           or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 23,
>           or use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.wear" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

I have looked up for this error in most of the stackoverflow post's and they suggested to change the minimum SDK version in the build.GRADLE (app module) file in the defaultConfig section to 23, and the error doesn’t appear when I change the version to 23 as below.

> defaultConfig {
>      applicationId "com.example.sai.wearexample"
>      minSdkVersion 23
>      targetSdkVersion 26
>      versionCode 1
>      versionName "1.0"
>   }

But, if I change the  minSdkVersion version to 23 then there is the below error while I want to run the application on the smartwatch.

[image]

I have looked into many of the answers in the stackoverflow but I am not able to get any of the specific resolutions for this question. I am stuck in between these two errors, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are no API 22 Android Wear devices anymore - you can safely assume minSdkVersion 23 for Android Wear devices and ignore the API 22 emulator.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - If I change the minsdk version to 23, then the error disappears but I won't be able to test the app on the smartwatch, what do you suggest on testing the app on the smart watch ?

Comment: update your watch. Every Wear watch got Android 6.0

Comment: @ ianhanniballake - Thanks, I will try to update watch and test the app.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Is there any way that we could fix this error without updating the android OS of the smartwatch, because if I select the pre-built template of watch-face in android studio, then I am able to test the apk on the smart watch. Although, for an empty activity, I am facing this error!

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Did you happen to look into this again?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use com.android.support:wear for api <23.

For the views you can add:

```
provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
```

And change in your java and xml the code for use the tools of

> com.google.android.wearable

instead

> com.google.android.support:wearable

For example, use android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout instead of android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout.

I hope I have helped.